# How to pass Laravel editable settings to Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have some settings in my app that can by changed by admin (like categories of products that every user can choose from when creating new product). I'm storing them in database 'settings' table that consists of 'name' and 'value' columns.

I also added a Service Provider that adds those settings to config and caches them. I can access them from Laravel easily, but not from frontend (using Vue).

Is there any way to access Laravel config values from Vue? I've tried [this answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/how-to-use-environment-variables-from-laravel-in-vue?page=0#reply=368165) but with no success. Should I make request for settings with every API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your setting is dynamic you must request them each time on a API call.

If not you can get those setting once when you deploy your fronted code.

Comment: Settings are dynamic, should i keep them in Laravel config and return `config('settings')` in Controller to avoid querying DB?

Comment: @Aryal
`config('settings')` under the hood does caching.
If you store your setting in the database, you must to re-validate setting cache each time it has been changed. Do you understand that?

Comment: That's what I want to do. Since settings will rarely be changed, I think I could benefit from caching them.

Comment: @Aryal do you really have performance problem? I would prefer avoid cache, if there are no need of it
`There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.` - Martin Fowler

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm understanding your question correctly but...

Laravel configurations are part of the backend. The only way to access them on the frontend is by passing them to it.

Unless there's some fancy trickery I'm not aware of, a Vue.js app, which loads and runs on the client-side, wouldn't have access to your server-side configurations -- unless there's something that say drags them in during compilation that I don't know about, which would strike me as risky at best.

But generally speaking, client-side headless app can't access server-side data unless the server says "here client, have this data."

E.g.

```
class MyApiController extends Controller
{
    function getThisConfig()
    {
          return config('this');
    }
}
```

With:

```
Route::get('/api/config/this', ['uses' => 'MyApiController@getThisConfig']);
```

And then your Vue.js app sends an AJAX request to `/api/config/this`.

Comment: Well, there is a way to [access environmental variables](https://medium.com/@onur.kose/laravel-with-vue-and-environmental-variables-8be093105c69) by using MIX_ prefix in .env file and I found some signs that it might be done with config, that's the fancy trickery I'm asking about :)

Comment: Some trickery I wasn't aware of indeed! But wouldn't this only expose it when Mix is involved though -- i.e. when your app is compiled? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#environment-variables

Comment: I think you're right. I would have to re run the app for changes to take effect. I'm gonna do the API call. What are your thoughts on caching the settings though?

Comment: I think it would be best to move away from using `config()` and `.env` for anything that isn't *explicitly* related to your app/Laravel configuration; things like database configuration, third-party API access keys, etc. It sounds like what you're adding (shop categories etc) would be better suited for its own handler; it's more the "configuration" of your store, not of your entire app's scaffolding.

Comment: As for caching... it really depends on the use case. It's great if it's required, but not worth worrying about if you don't need it. I'd say probably don't worry about caching until your daily requests are in the thousands.